# Object Sereialization, JAVA, Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, json

I have n object whose properties are being sent to a front end using REST protocols. There the object is taken in as an XML file and then parsed to JSON using JSON.parser. Now my target is to save this JSON file for some specified time on the disk. I tried serializing the object and storing it but it gets stored in binary/hex format. I need it to be in xml or JSON format.
Can anybody help me with this ?
Front-end is in JavaScript and the back-end is in Java.

Comment: This is definitely a JS issue. As the back-end Java has send the message in XML format through REST/http, it was already marshaled into text.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to save JSON file on client side disk, it is not recommended practice. Rather you should use [HTML5 web storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

Comment: I tried to save it on the server side by serializing the object. But it is in an unreadable format. How do i make it readable ?

Comment: You want to save on server side or client side? If you are planning to save on server side then use toString method on JSON or XML and first convert to string then save in file.

Answer (score 0):

are you using JSON.simple? if so, there are several examples on their page for converting a string to json and back. in this case you already have a deserialized object so you would just need to serialize it to a string see https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples

if you have your json object as a map you can

```
String jsonString = JSONValue.toJSONString(json);
```

or if it is already a JSONObject then simply

```
String jsonString = json.toJSONString();
```

then write the jsonString to your .json file.

```
FileWriter file = new FileWriter("/path/to/file.json");
file.write(jsonString);
file.flush();
file.close();
```

apologies if that is not the library you are using.